# onActivityResult is not working when calling the Camera Intent?

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I am using this Code to Call Camera Intent ...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        Log.d("========CALL  CAPTURE========= > URL ", "" + fileUri);
        Log.d("========CALL  CAPTURE========= > LOGGED TEXT",
                "===============>>>  LOGGED TEXT");
        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And onActivityResult method here to Receive the call

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.d("----------->> Request Code", "" + requestCode);
        Log.d("----------->> Request Code", "" + resultCode);
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Log.d("========CAPTURE========= > LOGGED TEXT",
                        "===============>>>  LOGGED TEXT");
                // successfully captured the image
                // display it in image view
                previewCapturedImage();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // video successfully recorded
                // preview the recorded video
                // previewVideo();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled recording
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to record video
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
```

But the Logs in onActivityResult  is not printing and giving me error...

The Logcat is :

```
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3195)
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at com.example.camerahandler.CameraHandler.captureImage(CameraHandler.java:72)
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at com.example.camerahandler.CameraHandler.startCapture(CameraHandler.java:49)
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at com.example.camerahandler.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:31)
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3571)
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14247)
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
08-25 19:43:33.459: E/AndroidRuntime(7034):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Calling `startActivityForResult()` from `onCreate()` of an activity is rather strange.

Comment: No i Have did it on Button Click ...

Comment: whats `(CameraHandler.java:72)`?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution as `Intent` Calling and `onActivityResult` is not in the Main View Class so having trouble .